# Expose a REST API via gRPC?

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'd like to interact with a REST API that I don't own, and I'd like to pass around protobufs inside my own application. I'd like to minimize the amount of boilerplate that I have to write, so my ideal solution would be to write up a gRPC service definition and rely on its machinery for serializing/deserializing messages.

I see that [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) lets me expose a REST API for my gRPC service. Is there a shim that goes in the opposite direction? i.e. something that lets me expose a gRPC API to my own code for an external service that speaks REST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need anything specific. Protobuf comes with a built-in json serializer and deserializer called `JsonFormat`.

This means you should be able to simply write a proto definition that conforms to your third party service. Inside your code, you use the actual proto objects. When speaking to the service, you use protobuf's json serializer and deserializer to produce the requests and parse the responses.

Comment: I'd like to be able to define a proto `service` and get stubs generated for me so that I don't need to write glue to match up proto `message` types with HTTP endpoints. I don't think I can avoid that by using `JsonFormat`.